# Total differential Economics Application

Tags: economics

Suppose we have a revenue function: $R= P*Y$ where $P=$ price and $Y=$ output and is a function of $P$ and $C$, $Y= Y(P,C)$.  How could we write the total differential of $R$ with respect to $P$ and $C$?

Here's where I am at:
$$
dR= \frac{\partial R}{\partial P}dP + \frac{\partial R}{\partial C}dC
$$

I am stuck trying to determine the partial of $R$ w.r.t. $P$ and $C$.  How should I deal with the $P$ that is being multiplied by $Y(P,C)$?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just use the product rule:

$$
\begin{align}
dR&=\frac{\partial \{P*Y(P, C)\}}{\partial P}dP+\frac{\partial \{P*Y(P, C)\}}{\partial C}dC\\
&=dP\left(Y(P, C)+P\frac{\partial Y(P,C)}{\partial P}\right)+P\frac{\partial Y(P,C)}{\partial C}dC
\end{align}
$$

Comment: After further investigating I don't believe the above answer is correct.  I agree with the first line but don't follow the application of the product rule seen in the second line.  Why would the partial w.r.t C include C.  I have something to the effect of dR= dP*(Y(P,C)+P*(DY(P,C)/DP)) + (DY(P,C)/DC)*dC   where D is the partial derivative operator.  Does this seem correct?

Comment: @user98167 Yes, naturally. Sorry for the confusion. Edited my post now.

Comment: @user98167 In your answer I think you are missing one part though. The last term should be multiplied by P (since you have $P*Y(P, C)$).